# Using while loops instead of pow: What does this error mean?

Tags: c

I am attempting to create some code with C programming that can show a number to a certain power with both values specified by the user. I want to use pow for the first part and a while loop for the second. However, I've confronted an error with this current code that I cannot seem to get rid of.

Here is ther error that I am unfamiliar with:

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int (*)(int,  int)’ and ‘int’)
       result2 = result2 * base;
```

I've tried looking into other questions with the same error, but they differ so much that I cannot understand.

I've tried researching into "long" but I have not been experienced with it yet through my C textbook, so I would like to refrain from using it if possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int result2(int base, int exponent);

int main(void)
{
    double base;
    double exponent;
    double result1;

    puts("Please enter a value as the base and another as the exponent.");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &base, &exponent);

    result1 = pow(base, exponent);

    printf("Library solution: %lf\n", result1);

    printf("My solution: %d\n", result2(base, exponent));
}

int result2(int base, int exponent)
{
    int i;


    for(i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
    {
        result2 = result2 * base;
    }
    return;
}
```

I would like to be able to calculate the equation properly using both methods with the user's values. However, with this error, I just cannot seem to get past and achieve that. Thank you.

Comment: Is `result2` supposed to be a function of an integer?

Comment: In Visual Basic, you set the return value of a function by assigning a variable sharing the same name as the function.  C doesn't work that way.  (Or C++, C#, Java, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result2(int base, int exponent)
{
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
    {
        result2 = result2 * base;
    }
    return;
}
```

`result2` is the name of your function. Rather than using it like a variable that can accumulate the results of the loop, you should create a variable to do that job. Then return the value of the variable at the end.

```
int result2(int base, int exponent)
{
    int i;
    int result = 1;

    for(i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Better yet, give the function a different name. `result2` sounds like the name of a variable. The function should be named something that indicates what it does. Since `pow` is taken, how about `power`?

```
int power(int base, int exponent)
{
    int result = 1;

    for (int i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
    {
        result *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Some other small improvements are declaring `int i` inside the `for` loop, and using `result *= base` as shorthand for `result = result * base`.

Answer (score 0):

i made a few modifications to your code.

1) Renamed funtion `result2` to `my_exp`. `result2` sound like a variable.

2) Modify types for funtion `my_exp` to `int` to be consistent with the variables types of `main`.

3) Add a variable `result` in `my_exp` to store the partial result of `for` loop.

4) Declared `i` inside `for` declaration.

5) call `pow` and `my_exp` inside `printf` and remove `result1` is not necesary anymore.

6) Changed how `result` is calculed to a more compact way.

most of those changes are cosmetic except for types changes.

```cpp
int my_exp(int base, int exponent);

int main(void)
{
    int base;
    int exponent;

    puts("Please enter a value as the base and another as the exponent.");
    scanf("%i", &base);
    scanf("%i", &exponent);

    printf("Library solution: %i\n", pow(base, exponent));
    printf("My solution: %i\n", my_exp(base, exponent));
}

int my_exp(int base, int exponent)
{
    //int i;
    int result;
    result = 1;

    for(int i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
    {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The function doesn't handle fractional exponents, so it would be better not to change the type of that parameter to `double`.

Comment: that is true, i edited my answer changing types to int